# Apply an attribute to a WCF service method to access Cookies

Tags: c#, wcf, custom-attributes

Is there a way to apply a custom attribute to a WCF service method that can access the Cookies header? The WCF service is REST based and will only ever be consumed over HTTP transports.

So far the only way I have found to get an attribute to apply to my WCF service methods is by implementing the IOperationBehavior interface. With that I can at least get my attribute instantiated and the IOperationBehavior methods get called but how do I get from there to somewhere I can access HttpContext.Current to get at the Cookies?

My attribute is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public MyAttribute()
    {
        int x = 1;
    }

    void IOperationBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    void IOperationBehavior.Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        int y = 2;
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        int y = 2;
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm applying it on my service method using:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public bool IsAlive()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[] in your service method to access cookies. You don't need to write custom attribute to achieve it

Comment: The point is I want to access the cookies in an attribute. I do some custom authorisation logic in an attribute and need to access teh cookies from it.